# How to fetch the data from a nested JSON file

Tags: python

I have a JSON File Which has 10 level of nested data in it.
What would be the best way to fetch data from it.

```
    [{'next': '?page=2',
     'previous': None,
    'results': [{'Accounts': [{'id': 17934,
                         'logo': '//112233.contify.com/client_data/custom_tag/logo/xsl0bzxk_400x400-17934.jpg',
                         'name': 'Tata Sons Ltd'}],
           'Channels': [{'id': 17,
                         'logo': '//112233.contify.com/images/tags-ico.png',
                         'name': 'News and Other Websites'}],
           'Content Types': [{'id': 3,
                              'logo': '//112233.contify.com/images/tags-ico.png',
                              'name': 'News Articles'}],
           'Duns Number': [{'id': 18847,
                            'logo': '//112233.contify.com/images/tags-ico.png',
                            'name': '650048044'}],
           'Sources': [{'id': 68636,
                        'logo': '//112233.contify.com/images/tags-ico.png',
                        'name': 'Factiva'}],
           'Triggers': [{'id': 15174,
                         'logo': '//112233.contify.com/images/tags-ico.png',
                         'name': 'Cost Reduction'}],
           'attachments': [],
           'duplicate_count': 1,
           'duplicates': [{'id': 20032653838695,
                           'source_name': 'Factiva',
                           'source_url': 'https://global.factiva.com/en/du/article.asp?accountid=9ERN000600&accessionno=TOIKOC0020200326eg3q00024',
                           'summary': 'As a result of the current air '
                                      'travel shutdown, Tata Sons may be '
                                      'strategically compelled to operate '
                                      'just one rather than two airlines - '
                                      'AirAsia India and Vistara, and Air '
                                      "India's privatisation is unlikely "
                                      'to proceed in FY21.',
                           'title': "'IndiGo, SpiceJet loss may hit "
                                    "$1.5bn'"}],
           'id': 20032653838666,
           'image_url': '',
           'previews': [],
           'pub_date': '2020-03-26T00:00:00Z',
           'source_name': 'Factiva',
           'source_url': 'https://global.factiva.com/en/du/article.asp?accountid=9ERN000600&accessionno=TOICHE0020200326eg3q0002c',
           'summary': 'AIR TRAVEL SHUTDOWNAs a result of the current air '
                      'travel shutdown, Tata Sons may be strategically '
                      'compelled to operate just one rather than two '
                      'airlines - AirAsia India and Vistara, and Air '
                      "India's privatisation is unlikely to proceed in "
                      'FY21.',
           'title': 'IndiGo, SpiceJet combined loss could hit $1.5bn: '
                    'Report'},
          {'Accounts': [{'id': 15159,
                         'logo': '//112233.contify.com/client_data/custom_tag/logo/thyssenkrupp-ag-15159.png',...........
```

I am able to fetch data one by one using a static Query like below

```
import json
with open("response.json", "r") as file:
  info = json.load(file) # info contains all key-value pairs
  for i in info:
      try:
          print(i["results"][0]["title"])
      except:
          print("")
```

Output:

```
IndiGo, SpiceJet combined loss could hit $1.5bn: Report
German ThyssenKrupp/ Cuts 3 thou jobs at steel business
Sameer Aggarwal Walmart India CEO
```

Edit1: I have normalized the JSON using the below script

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
print(df['results'])
```

Output:

```
0    [{'source_name': 'Factiva', 'attachments': [],...
1    [{'source_name': 'Factiva', 'attachments': [],...
2    [{'source_name': 'Factiva', 'attachments': [],...
3    [{'source_name': 'Devdiscourse', 'attachments'...
4                                                   []
5    [{'source_name': 'Factiva', 'attachments': [],...
6    [{'source_name': 'Factiva', 'attachments': [],...
7    [{'source_name': 'The Globe and Mail', 'attach...

Name: results, dtype: object
```

How do i fetch all the data using a loop?Please help i am new to python

Comment: Have you looked into json.normalize?

Comment: Your code after `with open() as` is not intended